# Switching between UITableView and MapView with same data source

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Ok so here it goes...I'm working on a project where users start with a search screen where they enter some criteria. When they submit the search, a UITableViewController is pushed in the UINavigationController and are presented with the results of the search. All of these items in the search results have a lat/long so we want to give the user the option to display the results in a map as well.

What we want is to be able to "switch" back and forth between the list and map view without adding anything new into the nav controller stack...meaning, if they switch to the map view and then hit the back arrow, they want the user to go back to the search screen. The other thing is, when switching between the list and map view, they want a horizontal flip effect, so it's somewhat clear to the user that they aren't pushing onto the nav stack.

So my problem is I can't figure out how to get this all working together. The closest I've got has been when switching between list and map, basically taking the array of VC's in the nav controller stack and replacing the last one (list) with the new one (map) and vice versa...but this seems clunky and doesn't offer any animation transition effects that i can find.

Any ideas? I'm probably over complicating it, but I've been stuck on this for a few days now and really needing some help.

Answer (score 1):

u can easily achieve this by using a view there is no need for using a separate view controller, for this u need a view controller instead of tableviewcontroller for example see the image, on top of tableview, so lets do like this, in your view controller contains tableview, add a separate view which contains your map view and back button as seen below image

[image]

in the `View-MapView` should be on top of tableview. in the above example i added a back button, and `aMapView` as a label so u can replace this with a map view.and button action is handled in same view controller that contains tableview

by this u are not adding any new thing to your navigation controller's stack

in the coding part u can use like below i took tableview's cell selection method to show this map view by flipping effect

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    //set map views co-ordinates
    //perform animation 
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.6 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
      [self.view insertSubview:self.mapView aboveSubview:self.aTableView]; //hear self.mapView is container view for botton and map view similar to `View-MapView` in the above image
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

   }];
}

 - (IBAction)backButtonAction:(id)sender {
   [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.6 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
      [self.view insertSubview:self.aTableView aboveSubview:self.mapView];
   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

   }];
}
```

Comment: wy down vote for my answer ... ? is there any thing wrong with my answer, if so can u comment it, so that i will make correction